# Including categories within expression engine

Tags: expressionengine, categories

I have created a list view of news articles within Expression Engine. A user can click through on each news article to read the detail. For each entry within the list view I would like to show its associated categories - ie the categories that it has been assigned to.

I am not quite sure how to combine this category information into my channel entries loop.

Comment: Might want to move this to the EE StackExchange site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

So within each returned entry in the loop, you want to display the category assignments? If that's the case, just use the [categories variable pair](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories) within your loop.